# Two files: keep lines with identical first n characters only

Tags: powershell

There are 2 text files in the CWD, `a.txt`, `b.txt`. From `a.txt`, I would like to **delete all lines whose first 5 characters are NOT present** in `b.txt` as any lines' first 5 characters. (Or, stating otherwise, keep only those lines in `a.txt`, whose first 5 characters **is** present in `b.txt` as any lines' first 5 characters.) Content after the 5th character to the end of the line is irrelevant.

For example: `a.txt`

```
abcde000dsdsddsdsdsdsdsd
0123456xxx
kkk
xyzxyzxyzfeeeee
kkkkkkkkkkk
```

and `b.txt`:

```
012345aabbcc
kkkkkkkhhkkvv
nnnnnnn5777nnnn77567
```

Intended result (lines in `a.txt` whose 1-5 character is present in `b.txt`):

```
0123456xxx
kkkkkkkkkkk
```

When I am running the code, it gives me an empty `results.txt`, but no error messages. What I am missing?

```
$pattern = "^[5]"
$set1 = Get-Content -Path a.txt
$results = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder
Get-Content -Path b.txt | foreach {
    if ($_ -match $pattern) {
        [void]$results.AppendLine($_)
    }
}
$results.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath .\results.txt -Encoding ascii
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your pattern doesn't match anything. The regular expression `^[5]` means "the character '5' at the beginning of the string" (the square brackets define a [character class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions)), not "5 characters at the beginning of the string". The latter would be `^.{5}`. Also, you never match the content of `a.txt` against the content of `b.txt`.

There are several ways to do what you want:

- Extract the first 5 characters from each line of `b.txt.` to an array and compare the lines of `a.txt` against that array. [Esperento57's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120086/1630171) sort of uses this approach, but in a way that requires PowerShell v3 or newer. A variant that'll work on all PowerShell versions could look like this:

  ```
  $pattern = '^(.{5}).*'

  $ref = (Get-Content 'b.txt') -match $pattern -replace $pattern, '$1' |
         Get-Unique

  Get-Content 'a.txt' | Where-Object {
      $ref -contains ($_ -replace $pattern, '$1')
  } | Set-Content 'results.txt'
  ```
- Since lookups in arrays are comparatively slow and don't scale well (they get significantly slower with increasing number of elements in the array) you could also put the reference values in a [hashtable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692803.aspx) so you can do index lookups (which are significantly faster):

  ```
  $pattern = '^(.{5}).*'

  $ref = @{}
  (Get-Content 'b.txt') -match $pattern -replace $pattern, '$1' |
      ForEach-Object { $ref[$_] = $true }

  Get-Content 'a.txt' | Where-Object {
      $ref.ContainsKey(($_ -replace $pattern, '$1'))
  } | Set-Content 'results.txt'
  ```
- Another alternative would be to build a second [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) from the substrings extracted from `b.txt` and compare the content of `a.txt` against that expression:

  ```
  $pattern = '^(.{5}).*'

  $list = (Get-Content 'b.txt') -match $pattern -replace $pattern, '$1' |
          Get-Unique |
          ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }
  $ref  = '^({0})' -f ($list -join '|')

  (Get-Content 'a.txt') -match $ref | Set-Content 'results.txt'
  ```

Note that each of these approaches will ignore lines shorter than 5 characters.

Comment: Thank you for the details. Which solution would you recommend to use if `a.txt` and `b.txt` both have 1 million+ lines (each line is a csv, 4 values [columns], maximum line length 400 characters)?

Comment: Probably the second one. Run some benchmarks first to make sure. For performance reasons some tweaks might be in order.

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
$listB=get-content "c:\temp\b.txt" | where {$_.Length -gt 4} | select @{N="First5";E={$_.Substring(0, 5)}}
get-content "c:\temp\a.txt" | where {$_.Length -gt 4 -and $_.Substring(0, 5) -in $listB.First5}
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is a concern, consider to use the hashtable(s) as index:

```
$Pattern = '^(.{5}).*'

$a = @{}; $b = @{}
Get-Content -Path a.txt | Where {$_ -Match $Pattern} | ForEach {$a[$Matches[1]] = @($a[$Matches[1]] + $_)}
Get-Content -Path b.txt | Where {$_ -Match $Pattern} | ForEach {$b[$Matches[1]] = @($b[$Matches[1]] + $_)}

$a.Keys | Where {$b.Keys -Contains $_} | ForEach {$a.$_} | Set-Content results.txt
```